# Are Queues possible in an Azure Logic App?

Tags: queue, azure-logic-apps

I am creating a azure logic app that is triggered daily that makes a series of web requests.  It it possible to add a queue to a logic app so that, on failure, the collection of requests will continue to process the next day?

Comment: You need to orchestrate it but practically anything is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the workarounds is to have a logic app inside a logic app. As you haven't provided any sample, Consider here is my request sending to my logic apps:

```
{"employees":[
{"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com","married":true},
{"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com","married":true},
{"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com","married":false},
{"name":"millie", "email":"millie22@gmail.com","married":true}
]}
```

and below is the screenshot of my logic app

[image]

so whenever there is a situation where the married property is false I'm sending the current item into a queue and then finally trigger my other logic app with the same workflow instead of waiting till the next day.
Now In the second logic app, I could able to manage the queue with required actions.

My second logic app

[image]

If in case you want the logic app to be triggered for the next day you can use the schedule trigger.